# Magento 2 - How to custom calculate amount of order when user login?

Tags: magento2, price, sales-order

In Magento 2, How to custom calculate total amount of order when user login?
[image]

Comment: You mean to say the cart/quote amount?

Comment: I've just update my question.

Comment: – MagePsycho: Yes